# How can I preform OpenSSL sign command in Java

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, digital-signature

I have a private key given by my customer. I need to sign a binary data using RSA algorithm. The OpenSSL command which perfectly works for me is:

```
openssl.exe rsautl -in InputData.bin -inkey private.key -out OutputData.bin -sign
```

How can I implement such signature in Java? I don't need to use any hashing algorithm, and my given private key is a 768-bit key.

I have written the following java code, but the signature created is not identical to the OutputData.bin file, and the verify method returns false. Can anyone help me identify what went wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

//Read the input data
byte[] data = readBytesfromFile("InputData.bin");

//Read the private key file
byte[] privateKeyBytes = readBytesfromFile("private.key");
String strPrivateKey = new String(privateKeyBytes, "UTF-8").replaceAll("(-+BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-+\\r?\\n|-+END PRIVATE KEY-+\\r?\\n?)", "");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(strPrivateKey));
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

//Read the public key file
byte[] publicKeyBytes = readBytesfromFile("public.key");
String strPublicKey = new String(publicKeyBytes, "UTF-8").replaceAll("(-+BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-+\\r?\\n|-+END PUBLIC KEY-+\\r?\\n?)", "");
X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(strPublicKey));
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

//Sign the file
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
sig.initSign(privateKey);
sig.update(data);
byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();

//Verify the signature
sig.initVerify(publicKey);
sig.update(data);
System.out.println(sig.verify(signatureBytes));
}
```

I have double check, and the public key matches the private key. I have extracted the public key out of the private key.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks, Guy Hudara

Comment: Have you tried testing your code with a key pair generated in your `main` method? That would at least narrow down whether the keys are at fault.

Comment: Yes I did. When using KeyPairGenerator everything works fine. But I need to use the Customer's private key, I cannot generate my own. Do I read the private.key file correctly?

Comment: Could it be that the public/private keys are not part of the same key pair? Note that using `NONEwithRSA` also makes you very vulnerable against attacks and mistakes. In general "raw" RSA should not be used.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have used the same private key file with the OpenSSL utility to sign my data, and used the public key in my java code to verify the signed data. Which was verified successfully. This proves that the private/public key pair matches each other. Correct? It must be something related to not reading the private key correctly from the file. BTW: My private key toString() method prints the following header: **Sun RSA private CRT key, 768 bits**. Is this OK?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, but I have created a key pair using `openssl genrsa -3 -out private.key 768` and impoted this into my code, and everything was fine. It must be something with my customer's private key.

Comment: What do you mean something related to my environment? I am using JDK 1.7.

Comment: One more piece of information: I now have two private keys: the working one (the one I have generated with OpenSSL), and the non-working one (the one i have received from my customer). I have used the toString() method on both keys, and noticed that the `prime exponent p`, `prime exponent q` and `crt coefficient` parameters are not in the same length although both are 768-bit. The length of these numbers in the non-working key is 60, while in the working key its 116 numbers. All other parameters have the same length. Can this be the reason?

Comment: This is RSA private key format http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2313#section-7.2